# How to access UIlabel, UIbutton, UIimageview or UItextfield using a string value - iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm developing an application that has a view with  `UILabel`, `UIButton`, `UIImageView` or `UITextField`.I want to create programatically the UIlabel, UIbutton, `UIImageView` or UItextfield with the information that i will receive from web service.

After create the UIlabel, UIbutton, `UIImageView` or `UITextField` programatically, how can I access then?

I will have a lot objects, and my idea was to have a name/ID to each one (I don't know if it is possible).

Then I would have a array with strings that have the objects names.

```
NSString *textFieldName = @"nameX";
```

Now with the name of the object how could I access then, for example to get the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need for that is using a tag, you put a tag to the view and then you retrieve like this:

```
 //first you put a tag in your fresh created view, for ex a button
 #define TAG_BUTTON 123

 myButton.tag = TAG_BUTTON;



//And you retrieve like this:

UIButton *myButtonRetrieved = [self.view viewWithTag:TAG_BUTTON]
```

Comment: Thanks, I had never seen the tag property.